What is an intuitive way to rename a column in a Dataset?
Given a simple Dataset e.g.
dataset = Dataset[{<|"old" -> 1|>, <|"old" -> 2|>}]

What is the most intuitive and easy to recall method for renaming a column?
Here is the most intuitive way I've found so far which isn't particularly intuitive:
Start:
Given that dataset[All, f[#]&] applies a function f to all rows (Associations) in the underlying Association structure:

We can write an f that renames the column:
e.g.
renameColumn[<|a___, HoldPattern["old" -> b_], c___|>] := <|a, 
   "new" -> b, c|>;

or
renameColumn[association_] := KeyMap[# /. "old" -> "new" &, association];


I feel my method is still hard to remember and not intuitive. Please feel free to suggest your method of choice. I'm curious to know if there is a more intuitive or better method out there.

Did you see Change Dataset Key Name ?

This query is an option for that:
dataset = Dataset[{<|"old" -> 1|>, <|"old" -> 2|>}];

dataset[All, KeyMap[StringReplace["old" -> "new"]]]


Thanks @Gustavo Delfino, I also notice that: dataset[All, KeyMap[Replace["old" -> "new"]]] also works

I often use this :
dataset = Dataset[{<|"old" -> 1|>, <|"old" -> 2|>}]
dataset[All, Association[#, "new" -> #old] &]
dataset[All, Association[KeyDrop[#, "old"], "new" -> #old] &]


I don't pretend this is intuitive.
In particular it uses the (documented) fact that Association[ blah1 , Association[blah2] , blah3] is equivalent to
Association[blah1,blah2,blah3]

This seems to work:

dataset = Dataset[{<|"old" -> 1|>, <|"old" -> 2|>}];
dataset /. <|a___, HoldPattern["old" -> b_], c___|> :> <|a, "new" -> b, c|>


Using AssociationThread as follows:
Dataset[# /. a_ :> AssociationThread[(# /. # -> "new" &@Keys[a]) -> 
Values[a]] & /@ Normal[dataset]]

In this version, the replacement happens faster.
